# flask-sqlalchemy slow paginate count

Tags: database, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Postgres 10 database in my Flask app. I'm trying to paginate the filtering results on table over milions of rows. The problem is, that `paginate` method do counting total number of query results totaly ineffective.

Heres the example with dummy filter:

```
paginate = Buildings.query.filter(height>10).paginate(1,10)
```

Under the hood if perform 2 queries:

```
SELECT * FROM buildings where height > 10
SELECT count(*) FROM (
  SELECT * FROM buildings where height > 10
)
--------
count returns 200,000 rows
```

The problem is that count on raw select without subquery is quite fast **~30ms**, but paginate method wraps that into subquery that takes **~30s**.

The query plan on cold database:

[image]

Is there an option of using default paginate method from flask-sqlalchemy in performant way?

EDIT:
To get the better understanding of my problem here is the real filter operations used in my case, but with dummy field names:

```
paginate = Buildings.query.filter_by(owner_id=None).filter(Buildings.address.like('%A%')).paginate(1,10)
```

So the SQL the ORM produce is:

```
SELECT count(*) AS count_1 
FROM (SELECT foo_column, [...]
FROM buildings
WHERE buildings.owner_id IS NULL AND buildings.address LIKE '%A%' ) AS anon_1
```

That query is already optimized by indices from:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_trgm_buildings_address ON public.buildings USING gin (address gin_trgm_ops);
CREATE INDEX ix_buildings_owner_id ON public.buildings USING btree (owner_id)
```

The problem is just this count function, that's very slow.

Comment: Did you add an index on `height`?

Comment: There is no reason for the subquery to be slow.  Maybe it just needs to read the data from disk, because it isn't yet in memory.  Try an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` of the queries.

Comment: The index on height is exists.

Comment: @jjanes the query without subquery had to be on the cache already while testing, so thats why there was a differencee between those two. Question is, whether we can speed up the pagination when no data in cache?

Answer (score -1):

So it looks like a disk-reading problem.  The solutions would be get faster disks, get more RAM is it all can be cached, or if you have enough RAM than to use [pg_prewarm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/pgprewarm.html) to get all the data into the cache ahead of need.  Or try increasing effective_io_concurrency, so that the bitmap heap scan can have more than one IO request outstanding at a time.

Your actual query seems to be more complex than the one you show, based on the `Filter:` entry and based on the `Row Removed by Index Recheck:` entry in combination with the lack of Lossy blocks.  There might be some other things to try, but we would need to see the real query and the index definition (which apparently is *not* just an ordinary btree index on "height").

Comment: I edited my question, and added a real filters used in my scenario (dummy table names and columns provided to get a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: pg_trgm does not actually support '%A%' very well.  It has to scan the entire index, and then the entire table, because %A% contains zero trigrams.  But that doesn't change the rest of my answer, the problem is not in how the query is formulated, but rather that the data is not in cache.